# React Login, Moving to new view once authorization is good

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm running into a road block trying to do something which I think would be rather simple.

My application is laid out as such:

```
├── src 
│   ├── background.jpeg 
│   ├── client.js 
│   ├── client.min.js 
│   ├── images.jpeg 
│   ├── index.html 
│   ├── js 
│   │   ├── client.js 
│   │   └── components 
│   │       ├── Footer.js 
│   │       ├── Header.js 
│   │       ├── Layout.js 
│   │       ├── login 
│   │       │   ├── Layout2.js 
│   │       │   └── Login.js 
│   │       └── Main.js
```

client.js loads the Layout2 component in this fashion:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from "react-router";

import Layout2 from "./components/login/Layout2";
import Login  from "./components/login/Login";

const app = document.getElementById('app');
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Layout2}>
            <IndexRoute component={Login} />
        </Route>
    </Router>,
app);
```

And Layout2 loads the Login component:

```js
import React          from "react";
import Center         from 'react-center';

import Login          from "./Login";

export default class Layout extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Center>
                    <Login>
                    </Login>
                </Center>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Finally Login is

```js
import React from "react";
import linkState from 'react-link-state';
import {Router} from "react-router";
import Layout   from "../Layout.js";

var _ = require('lodash');
var $ = require ('jquery');

export default class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      user: '',
      password: '',
      pin: ''
    }
    this._onEntry = this._onEntry.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    var styles = _.cloneDeep(this.constructor.styles);
    return (
      <div style={styles.loginPosition}>
        <form role="form">
          <div className="form-group">
            <br /><br />
            <input type="text"      class="form-control" valueLink={linkState(this, 'user')}     placeholder="Username"  onKeyPress={this._onEntry}/> <br />
            <input type="password"  class="form-control" valueLink={linkState(this, 'password')} placeholder="Password"  onKeyPress={this._onEntry}/> <br />
            <input type="password"  class="form-control" valueLink={linkState(this, 'pin')}      placeholder="Pin"       onKeyPress={this._onEntry}/>
          </div>
        </form>
        <br /><br />
      </div>
    );
  }
    _onEntry(e){
        var user    = this.state.user;
        var pass    = this.state.password;
        var pin     = this.state.pin;

        /* Look for the enter key */
        if (e.nativeEvent.keyCode != 13)
            return;

        if( user === "" || pass === ""  || pin === "" )
            return;

        /* Form the message for the backend */
        var message = { user: user, pass: pass, pin: pin, time: new Date() };

        var server = "http://blah/phpsomething.php";
        $.ajax({
            url:        server,
            dataType:   'json',
            type:       'POST',
            data:       message,
            success:    function(data) {
                if( data.status === true ){
                    alert("Access Granted");
                } else if( data.status === false ){
                    alert("Access Denied");
                }
            }.bind(this)
        });
    }
}
```

My questions is, once I've validated the user credentials, and I get the alert("Access Granted"), how do I change to another layout?

I have to load the login page first so I allow the user a chance to authenticate, but after that I want to load the Main.js component.

I've tried using this.context.router.push(); and window.location and etc.. but nothing I do seems to work, to change to the Layout.js, which has the rest of the views I want to use from that point on.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to push a new location via browserHistory or hashHistory.
In your case, you are using hashHistory, so:

```
import { hashHistory } from 'react-router'

if( data.status === true ){
  alert("Access Granted");
  hashHistory.push("URL to Main.js component")
} else if( data.status === false ){
  alert("Access Denied");
}
```

Add Main.js component to your react router:

```
import Main  from "./components/Main";
<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Layout2}>
        <IndexRoute component={Login} />
        <Route path="/URL to Main.js component" component={Main} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

Comment: Thanks :D, that worked like a charm, I finally got it working with that kind of solution last night, I did a play on your example, but it's doing what I want!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to save some flag describes successfully authorization (or token or something else) and check it with `onEnter` method each route you want to secure. You can read more about enter hook (react router) [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md#enter-and-leave-hooks)
For example: User try to access secured route `/secured`. React router understands that and call `onEnter` hook, where you can verify user's access permissions. In case of verification fail you can redirect user to `Login` route, otherwise user gets requested page.